# Verifying that Webforms Hooks are firing

Tags: hooks, webforms

I'm new to Drupal but relatively proficient in PHP.  I'm attempting to use the Webform module as a ticketing system.  What I'd like to do is hook into the webform submission insert (hook_webform_submission_insert) and create an object of type 'support_ticket' each time a webform is saved.  For now, I'm just trying to make sure that I'm hooking in properly, and it looks like I'm not.  I'm using the code below in a template.php file of a custom module:

```
function pvfk_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission){
   drupal_set_message("IN Insert");

   //Declare a new StdObj

   $new_node = new StdObj();
   //Set the type
   $new_node->type='support_ticket';

   //Set the Title
   $new_node->title='NEW TICKET';

   //Set the body
   $new_node->body = 'TICKET BODY';

   //Set other content fields
   // $new_node->field_name[0]['value'];

   //Finally use functions to save, submit, and insert the new_node
   $new_node = node_save($new_node);
   node_submit($new_node);
   content_insert($new_node);
```

I've cleared my cache and created new webforms - but neither a new piece of content is created nor do I see the message.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Hook functions are run only when they are put inside a .module file.

So you should move your function into your pvfk.module file. Then visit your /admin/build/modules list so Drupal will refresh hooks list.

Answer (score 0):

Moved it to the module as suggested by ermannob.  Still wasn't firing, finally realized the prefix should have been pfvk and not pvfk...lesson learned.